# compile angular component : how to put the html inside the js

Tags: angular

I have an angular 12 project, initialized by angular cli (and ionic.)

I don't use webpack

In the dist repo, I see the compiled files of my component, but not their html.
How can I put those file here?
I also know that it's possible to transforme the html into some code who will be in the .js file.
How do I do it?

Comment: FYI: The Angular CLI uses webpack under the hood, so if you are using the Angular CLI you are also using web pack.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular compiler converts your HTML and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code during the build phase before the browser downloads and runs that code. Compiling your application during the build process provides a faster rendering in the browser.

for more https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler